Is it possible to get usage statistics for an Android app in work profile?
Currently I managed to get the usage statistics for apps in primary profile, my code:
val usageStatsManager = ctx.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val events = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(currentTime - sec * 1000, currentTime)

while (events.hasNextEvent()) {
    val event = UsageEvents.Event()
    events.getNextEvent(event)

    // ...
}


But this doesn't work for app in work profile, is it possible to do that?

ey @aj3423, did you find out how to do it or any alternative? Thanks!
